# cygwin AtlGr+pipe key not working as a pipe but as a split vertical bar

Tags: windows-7, bash, keyboard, cygwin

In cygwin with Windows 7, when I type AltGr+backtick key, I expect a `|` pipe sign to be typed, but instead I get a pipe that is split in the middle `¦`, which won't act as a pipe sign in cygwin.

How can I reconfigure this to be a pipe sign instead? This doesn't happen anywhere else in the system, where I do get the `|` sign (browser, terminal via a VM, etc.). Any ideas?

Comment: Which language and keyboard layout are you using?

Comment: I believe it's en_UK

Answer (score 2):

On a UK keyboard, you can type the pipe symbol with Shift+backslash. AltGr+backtick does indeed yield the broken pipe symbol, but for me that's the same in any other Windows program such as Notepad, Firefox or the Command Prompt.

You could load the UK keyboard layout into Microsoft's [Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/goglobal/bb964665.aspx) and modify it. Or you could use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com) to create the appropriate mapping.

Comment: And is there an easy way to change that behaviour in the keyboard map? My brain seems to be wired to go straight to AltGr+backtick

Comment: Not sure about easy, but see updated answer.

Comment: I downloaded AutoHotKey but I am not sure how to remap the key. It seems like it's all about key combos for different purposes, but couldn't find the remapping section in the tutorial. Any ideas?

Comment: Nope, sorry. Maybe a new question specifically about AutoHotKey is in order.